# Is synthetic minority oversampling technique a good approach for small samples?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, inference, model, predictor

This question refers to the statistical performance (usefulness) of synthetic minority oversampling technique in small samples.

Suppose one has a data set with 300 observations, and two classes:

0 = 252
1 = 48

Is there any literature recommending (or not recommending) the synthetic minority oversampling technique for that type of small sample?

Comment: If you had 252-million $0$s and 48-million $1$s, what would you do?

Comment: In that case, I would be more confident that the 48 million 1 would represent the diversity in that class, and the noise created in the synthetic observations would likely be minimal. If I only have 48 1s, I think there's a high probability that the synthetic data won't be able to capture the diversity in this class - either by chance or selection bias.

Comment: What kind of analysis do you propose to do?  Surely, whether or not oversampling is useful (or harmful) will depend on your analysis, indicating there's no right or wrong answer to the question as presently stated.

Comment: Even more than on the analysis, it would depend on the classes and the data you have about them, eg. are they well defined or highly variable, well separated or overlapping....